# Simple_form Checkboxes with Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with simple_forms and my aim is to create a check box based on selection.
I should save it in an associative table.

I write models like

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :UserName, :cardno, :ctype
  has_many :items
end

class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddField < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :purchases, :ctype, :string
    add_column :items, :item_name, :string
     add_column :items, :purchase_id, :integer
  end

  def down
    
    remove_column :purchases, :ctype
    remove_column :items, :item_name
     remove_column :items, :purchase_id
  end
end
```

and I have written View like

```
<%= simple_form_for @purchase, :url => { :controller => 'payments', :action => 'show' } do |f| %>

<%= f.input :UserName, :label => "UserName:", :wrapper_html => { :class => 'uname_div'} %>
<%= f.input :cardno, :label => "Number On the Card:", :wrapper_html => { :class => 'uname_div'} %>
 <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :ctype, [[true, 'DebitCard'], [false, 'CreditCard']], :first, :last %>
<%= f.association :items, :label =>" Items Purchased:", :collection => ["Ac","Mobile","fridge"], :as => :check_boxes %>
<%= f.button :submit, :value => "Submit", :class => "sub_div" %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the data, it gives an error like

> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PaymentsController#show
>
> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: item_ids

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `item_ids` to the list in your model, like so:

```
attr_accessible :UserName, :cardno, :ctype, :item_ids
```

This will *whitelist* the given attribute and allow for mass assignment to occur.